# Sharing a single port with 2 VLANs on a Baystack 5510

Tags: switch, vlan

I have a Nortel Baystack 5510-48T (firmware says Avaya, but hardware says Nortel Networks). I currently have three different VLANs:

VLAN1 - management VLAN and also a VLAN, connected to a Cisco providing Internet access on a gigabit drop, that has all my Internet-facing NICs plugged into; is physically connected into VLAN2 so that LAN IPs can access its management telnet/web service;

VLAN2 - internal network LAN (10.0.0.x);

VLAN3 - Connected to a secondary gigabit drop, has VPN device plugged into it as VPN is on another IP block/circuit, with the VPN device also having a ethernet cable plugged from it into the VLAN2 network.

Right now I physically have the management network physically plugged into via an ethernet cable the LAN so that I can access it from the LAN (and by way of VPN).

What I want to do is make it to where the management port, port #1, is on its own VLAN (the management VLAN) but also is a member of the LAN VLAN (VLAN #2). It currently has a LAN IP address (10.0.0.254) and, again, is physically connected to the a LAN VLAN (VLAN #2) port. Is there a way to have a single port be a member of two VLANs? I know I could set it to where my management network is also the same as the LAN VLAN (VLAN #2), but I'm sure there must be some way to have a single port belong to more than one VLAN.

What can I do? I have full CLI access and am not afraid to use it.

Comment: I think theres no way a port can be a member of two or more vlan only in port channel or switch stack

Comment: You can set the port to untagpivdonly and assign the second vlan. Check the vlan configcontrol setting.

Comment: ` I know I could set it to where my management network is also the same as the LAN VLAN (VLAN #2)` -> why not simply do just that? What is the added benefit you hope to achieve with the setup you're thinking of?

Comment: @hertitu good question, maybe I will :D

Comment: @JuanDuarte I will look into that, thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Vlans by design can not talk to each other without a layer 3 device like a router.

A port can have one untagged vlan and many tagged vlans.

Untagged on a port means any traffic sent without a vlan tag like a computer will become that vlan number inside the switch.

Tagged means the port will handle the traffic that comes in with a vlan tag number.

Example... port 48 is untagged vlan 10 and tagged vlan 20 and 30

If you plug a regular computer into that port and don't tag any traffic the traffic will be vlan 10 "inside" the switch.

If you plug a switch into that port instead and send some untagged traffic and tagged traffic of 20, 30 and 40 it will handle all of it except it will disgaurd traffic with a tag of 40 because it's not tagged for 40.

Notice I have not mentioned ip addresses. These switch ports don't care about ip addresses. They are layer 2. That's controlled by your network card information until your network card has to send traffic to the gateway to be routed (meaning the computer needs to talk to an address outside its own subnet range)

Comment: What is going to plug into that port you want two vlans? If it's capable of tagging traffic we can do this. If you have a way of sharing a basic drawing I can show you where to tag, untag etc...

Answer (score 0):

Configure the port to be a trunk port. Trunk ports are allowed to carry frames belonging to multiple different VLANs.